# how to multiply two large numbers(say 512 bits) in java

Tags: java

i want to multiply two 512 bit integers in java and store the result.suggest some method to do  this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use java.math.BigInteger

A quick example of usage:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class BigIntegerTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigInteger b1 = new BigInteger("200000000000000000000000000000000001");
        BigInteger b2 = new BigInteger("400000000000000000000000000000000000");

        System.out.println(b1.multiply(b2));
        System.out.println(b1.bitCount());
        System.out.println(b1.pow(13));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

I suggest you use [`java.math.BigInteger`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

Comment: but i got a trouble.'*' opertion is not allowed on java.math.BigInteger types

Comment: @Bipul You have to use the multiply() method instead.

Comment: Because Java doesn't support operators overload.. but you will have some handy methods :)